# SQL: Changing Table's Data Column - Preserving Column Order

Tags: c#, sql

I've been assigned the task of changing some data columns in SQL tables (using Sql CE Server 3.5, if that matters).

The tables are populated from hundreds of Comma Separated Excel text documents.

The code makes a stab at determining the data type of the column and the table is created.

Later, I need the ability to come back in and say, "No, this column with 'Y' and 'N' need to be changed to a Boolean type instead of a Character type."

I have found information on how to [Alter the Table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) (drop a column and insert the new one), but would I be able to get the table's column back to the same Column Index value that it had before, like "Insert At Index=X"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just alter the column in place, then you won't have to worry about ordering it.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ALTER COLUMN myColumn Boolean
```

Comment: This was short and easy enough to test: `Data conversion failed.` Would all of the data need to be deleted first?

Comment: Oh -- yes, bool only takes 0 or 1 -- sorry, should have mentioned that.  You can express it as Y or N easy enough in a view or select later on.

Comment: BTW -- 0 = false or no, 1 = true or yes -- as far as most interpretations go.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to add a column at a specific index through ALTER TABLE. Tools like Sql Server Management Studio and Visual Studio Premium with Database tools can do it. But at least Visual Studio does it through a workaround:

1. Drop any constraints relating to the table, including FKs pointing at it.
2. Create a table with the new layout under temp name.
3. Move all the data (possibly including IDENTITY INSERT to preserve an IDENTITY column)
4. Drop the original table.
5. Rename the table with the temp name.
6. Recreate the constraints.

If you have the possibility, I deeply recommend Visual Studio Premiums DB project. Its deploy engine can handle this automatically for you.

Comment: That's the kind of answer I was afraid of. I don't do this enough to justify VS Premium DB.

Comment: If it isn't that frequent you can do it manually through Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of way to deal with this

1. Do as Anders noted which is to recreate the table from scratch
2. Don't rely on the table's column order. Instead use a layer of abstraction, for example  Views. (SQL Views or a .NET object view)
3. Don't drop and recreate the column but alter the column instead

That 3rd option is tricky because you'd have to update the values before the alter. 
For example

```
Create table #temp  (foo char(1), bar int)
Insert into #temp VALUES ('Y', 0)
Insert into #temp VALUES ('N', 1)

UPDATE #temp 
SET foo = CASE WHEN foo = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

ALTER table #temp  alter column foo bit
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

This is easy in the case. Converting a varchar(50) to a date-time for example would be a bit more difficult

Comment: Hmmm... that 3rd option was what I originally set out to do, but wasn't sure how to finish what I started. Can something like this be carried out in a T-SQL statement through Visual Studio in C#?

Comment: @jp2code. you could execute the DDL with `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` like normal. However its likely it would take two statements. One to convert the data and one to Alter. And not necessarily in that order.

Answer (score 0):

There is "dirty tricks" like this:

[Reset Identity Column Index](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/reset-identity-column-value-in-sql-server/)

But I, honestly, never did it, cause why you ever need to care about next index implied by DB. May be I'm missing something, but why do not construct your DB relationships on **your own** IDs, on which you can have total control.

Regards.

Comment: I'm only trying to do this because the Client wants his tables to be in the same order that they were in the Excel CSV file. It seems pointless to me, as well.

Comment: ok, but you can maintain the order requirements, but have one Identity column + all columns of your table, including YOUR own ID.